# How do I wrap C consts in a Ruby FFI module?

Tags: ruby, ffi

I have a (somewhat exorbitant) number of these:

```
extern TCODLIB_API const TCOD_color_t TCOD_red;
extern TCODLIB_API const TCOD_color_t TCOD_flame;
extern TCODLIB_API const TCOD_color_t TCOD_orange;
extern TCODLIB_API const TCOD_color_t TCOD_amber;
extern TCODLIB_API const TCOD_color_t TCOD_yellow;
extern TCODLIB_API const TCOD_color_t TCOD_lime;
```

How can I get at the values on the Ruby side nicely? It feels like there should be an attach_const equivalent to attach_function, as used below:

```
module TCOD
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib File.join(APP_ROOT, "libtcod-1.5.1/libtcod.so")
  attach_function :color_RGB, 'TCOD_color_RGB', [:uchar, :uchar, :uchar], Color.val
end
```

I'd prefer not to have to redefine everything from lightest_sepia to desaturated_chartreuse if at all possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is, `attach_variable` is what you're looking for.

This will work for anything that is actually a global variable (which looks to be your case) but not if the constants are just #define macros.

Quoting the [`FFI::Library` documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/ffi/ffi/FFI/Library#attach_variable-instance_method) for examples:

```
module Bar
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'my_lib'
  attach_variable :c_myvar, :myvar, :long
end
# now callable via Bar.c_myvar
```

and:

```
module Bar
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'my_lib'
  attach_variable :myvar, :long
end
# now callable via Bar.myvar
```

Comment: Pity there isn't a solution for #define constants too, but this helps :D

Comment: @Mispy: There is a solution for `#define` constants; see `FFI::ConstGenerator`.

Comment: @stopanko questions go in questions, not comments.